# how can i number each user input? C#

Tags: c#

Just started learning C#, my question is how do i keep record of the user input in order like this: `score 1:`

```
score 1: 98
score 2: 76
score 3: 65
score 4: 78
score 5: 56
```

In my code i can input the number but cant seem to setup the order how can i achieve this goal
my input:

```
98
76
65
78
56
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyGrade03
{
    public class Program
    {
        private int total;  // sum of grades
        private int gradeCounter; //number of grades entered
        private int aCount; // Count of A grades
        private int bCount; // Count of B grades
        private int cCount; // Count of C grades
        private int dCount; // Count of D grades
        private int fCount; // Count of F grades
        private string v;



        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public Program(string name)
        {
            CourseName = name;
        }

        public void DisplayMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the grade book for \n{0}!\n",
                CourseName);
        }

        public void InputGrade()
        {
            int grade;
            string input;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}",
                "Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100",
                "Type <Ctrl> z and press Enter to terminate input:");

            input = Console.ReadLine(); //read user input

            while (input != null)
            {
                grade = Convert.ToInt32(input); //read grade off user input
                total += grade;// add grade to total
                gradeCounter++; //  increment number of grades

                IncrementLetterGradeCounter(grade);

                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        private void IncrementLetterGradeCounter(int grade)

        {
            switch (grade / 10)
            {
                case 9: //grade was in the 90s
                case 10:
                    ++aCount;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ++bCount;
                    break;
                case7:
                    ++cCount;
                case6:
                    ++dCount;
                    break;
                default:
                    ++fCount;
                    break;

            }
        }
        public void DisplayGradeReport()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nGrade Report");

            if (gradeCounter != 0)
            {
                double average = (double)total / gradeCounter;

                Console.WriteLine("Total of the {0} grades entered is {1}",
                    gradeCounter, total);
                Console.WriteLine("class average is {0:F}", average);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}A: {1}\nB: {2}\nC: {3}\nD: {4}\nF: {5} ",
                    "Number of students who received each grade: \n",
                   aCount,
                   bCount,
                   cCount,
                   dCount,
                   fCount);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No grades were entered");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program mygradebook = new Program(
                "CS101 introduction to C3 programming");
            mygradebook.DisplayMessage();
            mygradebook.InputGrade();
            mygradebook.DisplayGradeReport();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not clear on what you want. Do a little research and effort especially on this school assignment.

Comment: is there anything you want to do with the ordinal of the input? is it just an index or will it be used for anything?

Comment: @dave i just want to know how do i get the score 1: numerical for each input

Comment: let me uinderstand: if i enter the first score as 98, and the 2nd score as 76, instead of just having 98,76 you want 1:98, 2:76? so later you can interrogates "what was score number 2"? i think you can only do this either by storing the data somewhere or using a list.

Comment: @jmike take a look on the MSDN link posted in the answer by Chris. `List<T>` has a couple of nice methods that you try to program yourself like `Sum()`, `Average()` and `Count()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of data structures that will allow you to store data in order. I'd personally recommend a [`List<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) for this.

You can add things to it as simply as:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(37);
list.Add(95);
```

And you can either read it with an iterator (`foreach(var score in list){...}`) or get individual numbers out (`var firstScore = list[0]`). The documentation will tell you more about what you can do with a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

declare one variable to count inputs like `private static int counter = 0;`
in `InputGrade` method, put like below

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}",
                "Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100",
                "Type <Ctrl> z and press Enter to terminate input:");
counter++;
System.Console.Write("score " + counter + ":");
input =  Console.ReadLine(); //read user input
```

and inside `while (input != null)` put like below

```
IncrementLetterGradeCounter(grade);
counter++;
System.Console.Write("score " + counter + ":");
input = Console.ReadLine();
```

so, output will be like
[image]

Here is the full code

```
    public class Program
    {
        private int total;  // sum of grades
        private int gradeCounter; //number of grades entered
        private int aCount; // Count of A grades
        private int bCount; // Count of B grades
        private int cCount; // Count of C grades
        private int dCount; // Count of D grades
        private int fCount; // Count of F grades
        private string v;
        private static int counter = 0;


        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public Program(string name)
        {
            CourseName = name;
        }

        public void DisplayMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the grade book for \n{0}!\n",
                CourseName);
        }

        public void InputGrade()
        {
            int grade;
            string input;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}",
                "Enter the integer grades in the range 0-100",
                "Type <Ctrl> z and press Enter to terminate input:");
            counter++;
            System.Console.Write("score " + counter + ":");
            input =  Console.ReadLine(); //read user input

            while (input != null)
            {
                grade = Convert.ToInt32(input); //read grade off user input
                total += grade;// add grade to total
                gradeCounter++; //  increment number of grades

                IncrementLetterGradeCounter(grade);
                counter++;
                System.Console.Write("score " + counter + ":");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        private void IncrementLetterGradeCounter(int grade)
        {
            switch (grade / 10)
            {
                case 9: //grade was in the 90s
                case 10:
                    ++aCount;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ++bCount;
                    break;
                case7:
                    ++cCount;
                case6:
                    ++dCount;
                    break;
                default:
                    ++fCount;
                    break;

            }
        }
        public void DisplayGradeReport()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nGrade Report");

            if (gradeCounter != 0)
            {
                double average = (double)total / gradeCounter;

                Console.WriteLine("Total of the {0} grades entered is {1}",
                    gradeCounter, total);
                Console.WriteLine("class average is {0:F}", average);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}A: {1}\nB: {2}\nC: {3}\nD: {4}\nF: {5} ",
                    "Number of students who received each grade: \n",
                   aCount,
                   bCount,
                   cCount,
                   dCount,
                   fCount);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("No grades were entered");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program mygradebook = new Program(
                "CS101 introduction to C3 programming");
            mygradebook.DisplayMessage();
            mygradebook.InputGrade();
            mygradebook.DisplayGradeReport();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for Collections available in C# ([MSDN Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz(v=vs.110).aspx)).

In your case, you don't really care about order, you can use `List<int>`. Otherwise if you want to keep an order you can use `Stack<int>` or `Queue<int>`. And if you want to keep a collection of Student Name + Score you can use a `Dictionary<string,int>`

Comment: `List<int>` will keep things in order as well. The difference between them and stacks/queues is that you can access any items in a list but stacks and queues only give back the contents in a very specific order. They all store the contents in the order you have defined it.